# updating QTableView cell after editing its content

Tags: python, qt, tableview

I tried checking around but couldn't really find an easy solution on this problem:
after allowing my TableView to be editable in its cell, I'd like to effectively update the just edited cell with the new value after pressing the "Enter" key.
I overridden the class TableView in order to customize the keyPressEvent event like this:

```
class MyTableView (QtGui.QTableView):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MyTableView, self).__init__(parent)
    self.parent = parent
def keyPressEvent (self, event):
    key = event.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
        index= self.selectionModel().currentIndex()
```

but now I don't know how to retrieve what I just entered before pressing the Enter key in order to update the table with this new value.
Any help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to customize your model instead of the view. Override the model's `setData` virtual method and pre-process new value there.

Comment: Check out the [Model Subclassing Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#creating-new-models) for help.

Comment: [Creating New Models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#creating-new-models) is helpful, as well. I'd recommend spending some time in that area of the Qt docs to get a feel for how the model/view framework works.